# Tracking Unity Particles Emitted

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, particle-system

How do I track the positions of particles emitted by a particle emitter?  I see the ParticleSystem.GetParticles and assume that's what I should use but its not clear to me how to do it.

Basically I want to know when a particle is off the screen so I can emit another one.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I got it.

```
  bool checkParticlesEmitted(ParticleSystem system)
{
    ParticleSystem.Particle[] m_Particles = new ParticleSystem.Particle[system.particleCount];

    int NumParticles = system.GetParticles(m_Particles);

    if (NumParticles > 0)
    { return true; }


    return false;
}
```